# How to detect if you are at the bottom page in flutter using webview?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, scroll

Cant detect the scroll in webview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVWGY.jpg)Currently this is my code. I tried to use  the scrollcontroller and set the gesturerecognizer as VerticalDragGestureRecognizer
if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
setState(() {
_reachedBottom = true;
});
} else {
setState(() {
_reachedBottom = false;
});
}

Comment: Pls Update your question. Instead of using a screen shot use: ``` [your code] ```

Answer (score 0):

Update your _controller in initState like this:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Setup the listener.
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
        bool atBegin = _controller.position.pixels == 0;
        if (atBegin) {
          /// here you are at the top
          print('here you are at the top');
        } else {
          /// here you are at the bottom
          print('here you are at the bottom');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```